# xpath query to find dynamic link by text

Tags: xpath, domxpath, xpathnavigator

Can we find the link with `[contain(text(),'text')]` with xpath query on page? I have tried to search it on page, but could not able to get. Am I running wrong query to find link by text? or it no possible? However, I am able to search link with `//a[text()='text_i_want_to_find']/@href`, this query work only if href contains '`text_i_want_to_find`'.

But what if link text is something link `'Hello world'` and href contains 'HelloWorld'. This make problem to work with dynamic link generation, where we have confirm link text but do not have any idea about, what href contains? How to handle such link, can we search link with text. Also, I want to know more about how xpath work for searching element on page. I would appreciate you inputs.

Comment: does the proposed solution work for you ?

Comment: No, it is still not working... Sample HTML link code  `<li>
<a id="Alert" href="AlertSettings.aspx">Alert Settings</a>
</li>` when I run xpath query `//a[contains(.,'ALERT SETTINGS')]/@href` or `//a[contains(.,'ALERT SETTINGS')]/@href` it does not return any value

Comment: can you post the url of the page you are working on ?

Comment: Sorry I can not provide you the url of page but above given html code is found for link

Comment: Another approach would be working on the id with such expression //a[@id='Alert']/@href

Comment: The contains() function is case-sensitive, that's why is does not work when you try to match with ALERT SETTINGS in your example. Try with 'Alert Settings' instead. I would say the answer given by @aberna is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand exactly what you are asking for I would suggest to use a partial match function using this pattern:

```
//a[contains(.,'text')]/@href
```

> fn:contains(string1,string2)  Returns true if string1 contains
>   string2, otherwise it returns false
>   http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp